# Disable Button but keep the color of the background

Tags: wpf, button, background, styles, isenabled

i have the following button style which works fine:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                        CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

with more styles defined at the button itself i change the buttons background (green for active)

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MainStatus.Restart}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

now if i disable the button, the button gets gray, because of the template. is there a way of making the current background more 'gray' but keeping the base color. so if the button was green, the color remains basically green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting background gray, you can ***set opacity to give it a disabled look*** (this will retain your background) something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />-->
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create style:

```
 <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```